# Another button that is not clicking

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is the HTML of the button I am trying to click with various options but its not working:

```html
<button data-ng-click="Question.setAnswer(button.value,button.attemptNext)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary " type="button">No</button>
```

I tried the following

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' and @value='No']"))).click();
```

but its not working 
TIA

Here is the console information.
i have been seeing the webdriver error before I  added the line
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Jan 27, 2020 1:03:02 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
WebDriverException occured

Comment: Here is the HTML <button data-ng-click="activeQuestion.setAnswer(button.value,button.attemptNext)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary " type="button">No</button>

Answer (score 1):

`No` is the text, not the value. Use

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' and .='No']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to pretty close. The `<button>` element doesn't have a `value` attribute but have the *innerText* as **No**

Additionally, *WebDriverWait* for the duration of `0` isn't an ideal configuration and must be set to a positive value.

However, the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to so to locate/interact with the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='attemptNext']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary ' and text()='No']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

I don't see any such error from the stacktrace you have provided. As you are still unable to click on the element inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) as an alternative you can use [`execute_script()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) as follows:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  element_css = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='attemptNext']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_css)
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  element_xpath = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary ' and text()='No']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_xpath)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the solution, but it is not clicking the button. new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary ' and text()='No'']"))).click();

Comment: @JOE_D Do you see any error? Error stack trace please?

Comment: I am very new to selenium eclipse, could you tell me how to do the error stack trace please? on the console it does not show much information

Comment: @JOE_D What ever the information appears within the console copy them and add to your question. We can intercept the relevant errors.

Comment: I just added the console message to the question

Comment: @JOE_D Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: i am still having the difficulty and i tried the latest update to try but its giving me the element_css cannot be  a variable type ..as i am trying it in Java. Appreciate your input. Why is the IDE not stopping but running the next code or not giving errors if it can find the element.

Comment: @JOE_D Is it a public url? Can you share the url?

Comment: sorry its not a public url I tried the code below too but its not working .. WebElement element=  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-sm btn-primary' and text()='No'']")));
          
          // WebElement element =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-sm.btn-primary[data-ng-click*='attemptNext']")));
          
          JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);